# How to remove Telegram?

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall, telegram

I have installed the official version of Telegram, but now I cannot remove it.

I have tried `apt remove telegram` and other methods, is there any trick to remove it completely?

Comment: Definitely, but we need more details. How did you install it? Did you download from the website or use the atareao ppa, or did you install it as a snap package?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you downloaded Telegram directly from the website, then your package management system has no idea about it, and you have to remove the files yourself. You may find them in `~/Downloads` but perhaps you put them somewhere else, for example `/opt`. If you have been using Telegram you may also find an automatically created directory in `~/Downloads` called `Telegram Desktop` which contains files you have downloaded from Telegram messages. There may also be a hidden directory in your home `~/.TelegramDesktop`. You can remove Telegram by deleting all these files and directories.

If you can't find them do`sudo updatedb && locate Telegram` to see where they are.

If you installed from the Atareao PPA then remove the PPA itself:

```
sudo apt remove telegram
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:atareao/telegram
```

As mentioned by @Anwar, there is a package called `ppa-purge` which removes ppas more gracefully, attempting to restore any packages from ppa to repository versions as well as removing the ppa versions. You don't need it in this case, since there is no repository version of Telegram, however, it is the preferred way to remove ppas:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:atareao/telegram
```

This will uninstall any packages from the ppa as well as removing it.

If you installed the snap package `telegram-sergiusens` then do

```
sudo snap remove telegram-sergiusens
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful information. i used locate command to locate files, then deleted the folder, and it's gone.  thanks again and wish you the best.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it @BassamM.Mardini :)

Comment: The user data is located under `~/.local/shares/TelegramDesktop`. It's important to also remove this directory for privacy protection.

Answer (score 9):

Run:

```bsh
sudo apt remove telegram-desktop
```

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 20.04 (I had downloaded the file from the website). I also manually deleted the Telegram folders from my `~/Donwloads` folder

Answer (score 7):

search and delete the "TelegramDesktop" folder.

in my case:

```
lsof|grep Telegram
```

revealed it was under:

```
~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/
```

Answer (score 6):

Telegram install in ubuntu with

```
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

You can remove it with

```
sudo snap remove telegram-desktop
```

Answer (score 4):

If you used flatpak:

Locate telegram flatpak id:

```
$ flatpak list
Ref                                                     Options       
org.telegram.desktop/x86_64/stable                      system,current
```

Uninstall Telegram:

```
$ flatpak uninstall org.telegram.desktop/x86_64/stable
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done:

```bash
find / -iname "*telegram*" 2>/dev/null
```

I found:

```bash
/home/marco/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop
/home/marco/.local/share/icons/telegram.png
/home/marco/.local/share/TelegramDesktop
/home/marco/Downloads/Telegram Desktop
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-bionic-universe/64x64/telegram-desktop_telegram.png
```

Comment: nice, bye-bye Telegram

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like you have downloaded the official executable file from the official website of Telegram. You can't remove it with your `apt` package manager because it has nothing to do with that because it is a `application/x-executable` type binary file. So in order to remove it completely do the steps I am writing below :

1. To remove the desktop entry/shortcut delete the following file (I'm using GNOME desktop in this case):

   ```
   /home/ri5h46h/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop
   ```

   deleting it will remove the desktop icon... you can also remove it using the `rm` command
2. Next delete the main executable file which may be in your Downloads folder

   Delete the whole folder which you extracted from the downloaded file.

   After doing above steps, telegram is removed 98% from your PC because still some files stay in `/home/<username>/.local` folder

   Following are those files, you can remove them if you want to

   `/home/ri5h46h/.local/share/TelegramDesktop` (This is a Directory)

   `/home/ri5h46h/.local/share/icons/telegram.png` (Telegram icon)

Answer (score 0):

I removed Telegram using [pLumo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182854/):

> This Telegram app just installs a `.desktop file`, its icon and a folder where it saves its data:
>
> Remove the folder with the Telegram and Updater file.
>
> Then run:
>
> ```
> rm -Rf \
>   ~/.local/share/icons/telegram.png \ 
>   ~/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop \
>  ~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop
> ```