# Why this icon apears on my bar?

Tags: unity, icons, 16.10, telegram

How can I remove it? I think this is from Telegram but I uninstalled it.
When it was installed it was the exact icon there but with some Telegram options to chose.

[image]

Maybe this can help you:

```
KiB Swap:  4091900 total,  3984412 free,   107488 used.   688468 avail Mem 

  PID USUARIO   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     HORA+ ORDEN       
 6597 root      20   0  333336  88340  59492 S  14,1  2,2   1:34.22 Xorg        
 7539 yami      20   0 1554200 217316  59584 S  12,2  5,5   1:22.30 compiz      
 9332 yami      20   0 1105920 293844  90652 S   5,6  7,4   1:49.35 chrome      
10821 yami      20   0  732468  36216  28620 R   5,3  0,9   0:01.22 gnome-term+ 
  893 root      20   0   32792   3840   3756 S   2,3  0,1   0:19.84 bluetoothd  
 8302 yami      20   0 1056816 262684  79936 S   1,6  6,7   0:18.48 chrome      
  935 root      20   0    4388   1240   1196 S   1,3  0,0   0:11.19 acpid       
 8173 yami      20   0 1328416 222392  86928 S   1,0  5,6   1:29.44 chrome      
 8598 yami      20   0 1092328 290372  91788 S   1,0  7,4   0:18.14 chrome      
10840 yami      20   0   45756   3872   3232 R   1,0  0,1   0:00.33 top         
  487 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:02.60 kworker/u9+ 
 5879 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.98 kworker/u8+ 
 6244 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.63 kwork
```

Or this:

```
KiB Swap:  4091900 total,  3984412 free,   107488 used.   688468 avail Mem 

  PID USUARIO   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     HORA+ ORDEN       
 6597 root      20   0  333336  88340  59492 S  14,1  2,2   1:34.22 Xorg        
 7539 yami      20   0 1554200 217316  59584 S  12,2  5,5   1:22.30 compiz      
 9332 yami      20   0 1105920 293844  90652 S   5,6  7,4   1:49.35 chrome      
10821 yami      20   0  732468  36216  28620 R   5,3  0,9   0:01.22 gnome-term+ 
  893 root      20   0   32792   3840   3756 S   2,3  0,1   0:19.84 bluetoothd  
 8302 yami      20   0 1056816 262684  79936 S   1,6  6,7   0:18.48 chrome      
  935 root      20   0    4388   1240   1196 S   1,3  0,0   0:11.19 acpid       
 8173 yami      20   0 1328416 222392  86928 S   1,0  5,6   1:29.44 chrome      
 8598 yami      20   0 1092328 290372  91788 S   1,0  7,4   0:18.14 chrome      
10840 yami      20   0   45756   3872   3232 R   1,0  0,1   0:00.33 top         
  487 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:02.60 kworker/u9+ 
 5879 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.98 kworker/u8+ 
 6244 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,3  0,0   0:00.63 kwork
```

Comment: Have you restarted your system after removing that app?

Comment: Yes, I did twice :S

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't remove the program completely. Try follow this instructions: [How to remove Telegram?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819521/how-to-remove-telegram)

Comment: Didn't worked but thank you very much for your help ;)