# How do I uninstall Telegram which was installed from the tar.xz obtained from the official website?

Tags: apt, tar, software-uninstall, telegram

I installed Telegram by visiting https://desktop.telegram.org/ and downloaded a `tar.xz` file. After which I ran

```
tar -xJf telegram.tar.xz
```

which uncompressed the `tar.xz` file and gave me `Telegram` and `Updater` in a folder.

Both the files have an `executable (application/x-executable)` as their type. I installed Telegram by double clicking the Telegram file.

Now, I'm not sure how do I uninstall it. I tried

```
apt remove telegram
```

but it said "Unable to locate package telegram" since it wasn't installed from apt. How do I properly uninstall Telegram Desktop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This Telegram app just installs a `.desktop` file, its icon and a folder where it saves its data:

Remove the folder with the Telegram and Updater file.

Then run:

```
rm -Rf \
  ~/.local/share/icons/telegram.png \ 
  ~/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop \
  ~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop
```

Answer (score 7):

> I installed Telegram by double clicking the Telegram file.

No, you didn't *install* Telegram by double clicking, neither `apt` was involved in any way. The `tar.xz` package contains a pre-compiled executable for Telegram Desktop and it  executes it every time you launch it. Simply delete the extracted folder to get rid of Telegram.

---

Also follow the [answer by @pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182854/480481) to remove other residue files.

Comment: I have managed to remove the telegram from @ pLumo's solution. But I get some idea of what actually happened when I double clicked on the Telegram from your answer. I would like to know more about what exactly happened under the hood. Do you know any relevant article that you can point me to? Thanks

Comment: You can check the official GitHub repo: https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you did it, Telegram is not really "installed" anywhere other than where you unpacked the `telgram.tar.xz` file. It runs directly from that location. When you unpacked it you got a `Telegram` directory, right? Just remove that, then Telegram is gone.

The `apt remove` way of removing packages generally works when that package was installed using `apt install`.